# How to get the value of parameter in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

```
public class Sender extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    Test t=new Test();
    StringBuilder a=player;

  }

  public void attackPlayer(StringBuilder player){
    System.out.println("code"+player);
  }
}
```

i want to store the value of `player` in variable `a`. Is it possible to get the value of parameter

Comment: How about a member variable?

Comment: You want the value passed to a method that isn't being called?

Comment: Actually I'm new in java so i don't know much more about it I just want to the "player" value in "a" variable.

Comment: If you are new to java, I suggest learning the core language before you attempt a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using doPost() method, you must pass parameter by a http-post request. Or if you want to pass parameters through URL, then you must catch the parameter in doGet() method in your servlet.

```
http://example.com?username=Miiii&pass=123
```

In above URL, `username` is a parameter having `value` = `Miiii` 
and same with `pass` too. and two parameters are separated by `&`.

If you want to hide your parameters and their values, you can send them through a form in HTML and select `method=POST` in form attribute.
This form (POST method) parameters will call doPost() directly, so catch them in doPost().

Also in your servlet; the way to get parameter is :

```
 // see the same way in doGet() and doPost().. no change in catching style


 String user = request.getParameter("username");
 String password = request.getParameter("pass");

  NB:
 "username" must be exactly same as **username** = Miiii & pass...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about request parameters, e.g.

```
http://yoururl.com?player=fred
```

then you can retrieve them using

```
String player = request.getParameter("player");
```